# Create a lengthy list of variable names in python with for loop

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop

I have a bunch of data frames whose names are `Actuals_17, Actuals_18,...Actuals45`.
I would like to create a list of these variables. I know that it can be created by manually typing:

```
varlist = [Actuals_17,Actuals_18,Actuals19,Actuals20]
```

However, it would not result in a neat code if the number of variables are large. Is there a method to make the ***varlist*** with a for loop?

Comment: Probably easiest to do when you create the data frames, assuming you use some common code for the creation.

Comment: your dataframes are stored in files?

Comment: Yes, I read them from files

Comment: Creating many similar variables referring to similar objects is wrong. You should have created a list of dataframes in the first place.

Comment: Create the list when you create the data frames. Instead of `Actuals_17 = ...`, use `actuals.append(...)`, where `actuals` is list you created previously.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python built-in [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) function which returns a dictionary representing the current global symbol table.

```py
varlist = [globals()[f'Actuals_{i}'] for i in range(17, 46)]
```

Comment: The dictionary *is* the global symbol table